# Laravel sync a Pivot table with 3 models relationships Many to Many and One to Many

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**Information:**

- A sound company has many employees.
- The employee has many positions in the company.
- The company has many events. And for every event, they need a crew.
- A crew is composed of many employees holding certain positions. An employee can hold multiple positions in a crew.

---

**For example:**

The list of employees is:

- Employee 1 is a **Driver**, **Sound Engineer** and **Stage Hand**
- Employee 2 is a **Driver**, **Sound Engineer**
- Employee 3 is a **Sound Engineer** and **Stage Hand**
- Employee 4 is a **Stage Hand**
- Employee 5 is a **Stage Hand**

The event is called: Event 1

- The crew is:

  - For the position of Sound engineer:

    - Employee 1
    - Employee 2
  - For the position of Stage Hand:

    - Employee 3
    - Employee 4
    - Employee 5
  - For the position of Driver:

    - Employee 2
    - Employee 1

---

**Problem:**

I believe this is done by using a pivot table that holds the **event_id**, **employee_id** and **position_id**

But when I follow this approach, I get stuck on feeding the data and the methods to use to create new data.

Is there a different approach?

Comment: So any chance you ever found a good way to do this? Right now I'm thinking I'll have to fall back on raw SQL

Answer (score 0):

you need two pivot tables. One for employee and position which hold employee id and position id. Another one between employee and event which holds event id and employee id. I think this is a better way to handle this. You can use the attach and detach method handling pivot table in laravel.

Comment: If I follow this approach, how would I know which positions the employee has in a crew?